# ajax based notification/messaging system

Tags: ajax, chat

I have a question.
Facebook probably uses ajax to notify user about a new message, is this correct?
If yes, would not this tax db to incredible levels?
I mean millions of users every second of being online requesting message status.
Or am I thinking about this in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about a technique called *polling*.  And you are correct that it has scalability issues.  In general not a good idea.

[rant]I have no idea what facebook does.  I hate facebook.  It's like a drunk whore who won't stop texting/emailing you and needs to be used.[/rant].

There are better alternatives to polling.  One technique is called *long polling*, and then there is *server side push*.

See
[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883540/http-server-to-client-push-technologies-standards-libraries.

In long polling, the client sends a request but does not expect a response immediately; the response could come immediately, in a second, or in an hour.  The challenge is for the server to manage the outstanding requests in a non-resource intensive way.

With server side push, the server maintains a connection with clients and can broadcast messages to its connections when events occur.

Which alternative to use depends a bit on your technology stack.  For example, node.js has something called socket.io (which I think is server side push using html5 websockets) which I hear good things about.